# Determine which type of exception is the throwable

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, throwable

This is the code that currently have that is working:

```
.whenComplete((r, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable != null) {
        logger.error("exception");              
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead, to determine if the throwable is a certain type of exception?

```
.whenComplete((r, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable == CertificateException) {
        logger.error("cert exception");             
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use the instanceof operator: if( throwable instanceof CertificateException ) { do something... }

Comment: `whenComplete` comes from...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `instanceof` keyword to find the type

```
if (throwable instanceof CertificateException)
```

And if throwable is wrapped around with parent like `Exception` or `Throwable` then use `getCause()`

```
if (throwable.getCause() instanceof CertificateException)
```